# Why Mandatory ASLR (Force Randomization for images) in Windows defender has issues with portable apps?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

I'm using the latest build of Windows 10, 1909.
when I turn on Mandatory ASLR in Windows Defender Exploit Protection, I can't launch portable programs.

for example I have Internet Download manager and some other programs as portable but they show erros on launch.

so I'm wondering, why is this happening only to portable apps? what's special about them?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Force ASLR has an option "disallow stripped images"; if enabled, images that can't be relocated in RAM don't run. Is this it?